# Unable to find type [namespace.className]

Tags: c#, powershell

While executing `[General.Program]::Main()` command in the powershell. It gave below error.

```
Unable to find type [General.Program].
At line:1 char:1
+ [General.Program]::Main()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (General.Program:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace General
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculate(10);
        }
        public static int Calculate(int value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello: The value is {value}");
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Commands which is used in powershell window are as follows

```
dotnet run -v m
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Resolve-Path .\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\General.dll).path)
[General.Program]::Main()
```

Attaching the screenshot
[image]

Folder structure
[image]

Comment: You can't just type `[General.Program]::Main()` into Powershell, you need to use the path to the executable file that has been built. For example `./bin/Debug/net6.0/general.exe`

Comment: That would be simple execution of the .exe file which I don't want in this case. I would like to access C# class/methods in the powershell.

Comment: you will need to create a class library not console and then call the class methods with params.

Comment: When I ran `dotnet run -v m` command, it created the General.dll along with General.exe.
I have added the screenshot in the question.

Comment: yeah I am sure it did... because there is nothing wrong with the code...you just need to select a different type: "class library"...good luck